# Nginx redirect to external port

Tags: node.js, redirect, nginx

Have config looking something like this.

I now want the main entry to domain to be :80.

So its only nginx that can redirect to :3000 and :8081.

If the user types domain.com:3000 -> i want it to be redirected to domain.com:80.

Is that possible and still have the functionality below, whith redirection based on cookie?

```
map $cookie_version $mybackend {
 default "127.0.0.1:3000";
 "v1" "127.0.0.1:8080";
 "v2" "127.0.0.1:3000";
}
...
location / {
  proxy_pass http://$mybackend;
}
...
location ~ ^/(?<cver>v[12])/ {
 ...
 add_header Set-Cookie "version=$cver;Domain=localhost;Path=/";
 rewrite ^/v[12]/(.*)$ /$1 redirect;
```

}

Comment: You don't need that. 127.0.0.1 is only available from the same machine.

Comment: ok, maybe i was unclear.
This is just for test purpose. 
Its "if the user types domain.com:3000 -> i want it to be redirected to domain.com:80."

Comment: If user types `domain.com:3000` he gets to app that listen port 3000 and it's not nginx. Usually these apps don't listen external interfaces, only to localhost, so typing `domain.com:3000` gets you nowhere and you'll end up with browser 'cannot connect' page.